# is this possible to change the choose button text in iphone photo album?

Tags: iphone, photolibrary

In my application i want to change the choose button text into done on iphone photo album...before that i want to know is there a possibility to do this...if possible means tell me how to achieve?

anyone please give me a solution for this...

Thank You for consideration and effort..

Is this possible to change the choose button title???

Comment: Hello...no answer for this question ah?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the built in photo album application, then no, you cant change that. You can however make your own photo picker and change the text there.